# Forget signed-in account AzureAD MSAL

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Is it possible to programmatically `forget` a signed-in Azure AD user?

I see this functionality in office.com. See image below.

Note:

- `Forget` an account can be done manually using the `Pick an account` > [https://login.microsoftonline.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0lFs.jpg)
- `msal.js` logout() does not forget the account.

[image]

Comment: I see that office.com is hitting `https://login.microsoftonline.com/forgetuser?sessionid=xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx` when Forget this account is selected. I'm not finding `forgetuser` documented on MS sites.

Comment: Oh I've never seen that endpoint. It's definitely undocumented.

Comment: Thanks @juunas  I'm able to get it working by using the sessionid from the msal localstorage.  `localStorage.getItem('msal.session.state')`  I can use postman and it works.  However, I get a CORS error when I try http get in my application.

Comment: Maybe they only allow this feature from like office.com :)

Comment: OK.  I believe I figured it out.  Instead of using a REST GET.  An hidden iframe with a src of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/forgetuser?sessionid=xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx` hits the endpoint and `forget's` the signed-in user.  No CORS error and response is correct.

Comment: @DeanB_Develop You can post your solution in the answer and make it. It is very helpful.